# Issue in applying the xml fonts and structure to .abc files in Ecllipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have files with extension .or and .chk in my application, I have opened these files in XML editor using File Association feature in eclipse and eclipse not able to apply the basic fonts and structure of XML on these .or and .chk files, but when I opened the .xml file in xml editor in eclipse they are looking good to me in structure as well as in font.

So my concern is that how to apply the default XML fonts and structure to these .or and .chk file, Please keep in mind that I have already associated these type of files with XML editor in Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but in addition to (or instead of) associating them with the editor, add them to the XML Content Type on the **Content Types** preference page:

[image]

The **XML Editor** already associates itself to the XML Content Type.